# pandas dataframe: len(df) is not equal to number of iterations in df.iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to print each row to a different file. When the dataframe consists of e.g. only 50 rows, `len(df)` will print `50` and iterating over the rows of the dataframe like

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index)
```

will print the index from `0` to `49`.

However, if my dataframe contains more than 50'000 rows, `len(df)`and the number of iterations when iterating over `df.iterrows()` differ significantly. For example, `len(df)` will say e.g. 50'554 and printing the index will go up to over 400'000.

How can this be? What am I missing here?

Comment: because [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) returns the column name series pair, check the docs

Comment: You probably also would be better to use `df.shape` and index the dimension you need

Comment: Just curious - but are you seriously aiming to create 50k files?

Comment: I know, I know, but sm1 asked me  to do it because they need files for a further step with another tool...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, as @EdChum noted in the comment, your question's title refers to `iterrows`, but the example you give refers to [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html), which loops in the orthogonal direction to that relevant to `len`. I assume you meant `iterrows` (as in the title).

Note that a DataFrame's index need not be a running index, irrespective of the size of the DataFrame. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=[2, 4, 5, 1000])

>>> for index, row in df.iterrows():
...     print index
2
4
5
1000
```

Presumably, your long DataFrame was just created differently, then, or underwent some manipulation, affecting the index.

If you *really* must iterate with a running index, you can use Python's [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> for index, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
...     print index
0
1
2
3
```

(Note that, in this case, `row` is itself a tuple.)

Comment: and yes, I meant `iterrows()`, sorry for the mistake.